# javascript validate enum in multiple select option input field

Tags: javascript, enums

I am writing a node application. I have a variable with `enum` values in model like this

```
day_of_week: {type: String, enum: ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday', 'weekends', 'weekdays']}
```

On the client side I have the multiple select input field like this
[image]

If I select one option in the input field it saves the content to my database which is mongoDB.

Else if i select more than one option in that it shows `enum validation error`.

How can we use `enum` in multiple select options efficiently if we have multiple choices and too many combinations for the input value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! I am posting the answer here so that it might be useful to someone else.

By making the day_of_week an array.

```
day_of_week: [{type: String, enum: ['weekdays', 'weekends', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']}]
```